# Weird hiccup removing duplicates from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I'm running into a weird glitch. I have a bit of code where I'm running thru an array of arrays, grabbing a bunch of city names and concatenating them all together. I need to remove the duplicates from the finished list. This should be pretty simple. Use a count to figure out which city has more than one instance and then splice them out. My returned array isn't coming out right though and I'm not sure why. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

```
const input = [
{
    name: "ACH2000",
    year: 2005,
    cities: ['Chicago', 'New York', 'Ames', 'Columbus'],
    ages: [12, 32, 2, 51]
},
{
    name: "FXG3000",
    year: 2008,
    cities: ['Chicago', 'Joliet', 'Plymouth', 'Dallas'],
    ages: [12, 32, 2, 51]
},
{
    name: "GTG1234",
    year: 2012,
    cities: ['Indy', 'Tampa', 'Houston', 'Dallas'],
    ages: [12, 32, 2, 51]
}
];

function getUniqueCities(data){
  let citiesInArray = data.map(function(item){ return item.cities });
  let concatCities = [].concat.apply([], citiesInArray);
  let count = {};
  for(let i = 0; i< concatCities.length; i++) {
      let num = concatCities[i];
      count[num] = count[num] ? count[num]+1 : 1;
      if(count[num] > 1){
        console.log('bad',num);
        concatCities.splice(num, 1);
      } else {
        console.log('good',num);
      }
  }
  console.log(count);
  console.log(concatCities);
}

getUniqueCities(input);
```

Comment: Do you actually need to know which cities appeared more than once, or it is enough to simply return a list with no duplicates? Anyway, think about what happens to the indices of items in the array *after* the item you are `.splicing()` out...

Comment: which is the returned array ? the `console.log(concatCities)` gives unique cities?

Comment: @nnnnnn Just a list with no duplicates. I think you've got a point about the indicies. I think splicing them out is what's causing my problem.

Comment: Yeah, if you splice while iterating you have to adjust the loop counter. Or just loop backwards from the end of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
var input = [
    {
        name: "ACH2000",
        year: 2005,
        cities: ['Chicago', 'New York', 'Ames', 'Columbus'],
        ages: [12, 32, 2, 51]
    },
    {
        name: "FXG3000",
        year: 2008,
        cities: ['Chicago', 'Joliet', 'Plymouth', 'Dallas'],
        ages: [12, 32, 2, 51]
    },
    {
        name: "GTG1234",
        year: 2012,
        cities: ['Indy', 'Tampa', 'Houston', 'Dallas'],
        ages: [12, 32, 2, 51]
    }
];

var citiesStats = {};

input.forEach(data =>
    data.cities.forEach(city => {
        if (!citiesStats[city]) {
            citiesStats[city] = 0;
        }
        ++citiesStats[city];
    })
);

var cities = Object.keys(citiesStats);

// ["Chicago", "New York", "Ames", "Columbus", "Joliet", "Plymouth", "Dallas", "Indy", "Tampa", "Houston"]
console.log(cities);
// {"Chicago":2,"New York":1,"Ames":1,"Columbus":1,"Joliet":1,"Plymouth":1,"Dallas":2,"Indy":1,"Tampa":1,"Houston":1}
console.log(citiesStats);
```

Comment: Note that if all you care about is the final duplicate-free list then the inner loop can just contain a one-liner `citiesStats[city] = 0` (or =true or whatever - the value doesn't matter).

Answer (score 1):

As [nnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360225/weird-hiccup-removing-duplicates-from-an-array#comment71870807_42360225) suggested splicing inside the loop is messing up the indices in the array.

If you can use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), here is a solution:

```
Array.from(new Set(concatCities))
```

Here is a link to [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sayan751/qegf72em/1/).